# How to align gridView using XML and Layout?

Tags: android, gridview

How to align gridView using XML and Layout?

[image]

I have tried a lot of attributes and methods, alignment occurs ONLY in the horizontal direction, and I need and vertically

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Add your image to the question and not as link

Comment: Please read what I write).I can't, little reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For Linear , you can use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working
Why this cannot be done with LinearLayout?

Comment: You won't believe). But yesterday I have exactly the same code as you wrote, and I have not worked. gridView was up horizontally, vertically, it is not installed....I'm the only ORIENTATION is not indicated. By the way, why do you not pointed it out?

Comment: thats why i like using relativeLayout, so much easier than linear ;)

Comment: The main part is actually the layout_height of the girdview.
You set it to match_parent will make it occupy the whole area of the parent. so it cannot be "center" (because it occupies the whole area, so it is already at the center!!). Change it to wrap_content will show you the result you want

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```